# Access error in Windows 7

Tags: c#

I am working on a windows appliciation in which i create a folder at runtime and save some xml files in the folder....
Every thing works fine in Windows XP but when i run this in Widows 7 / Vista i get the error saying Access to the path is denied..
i am creating the folder in C:\Programfiles\MyApplication\

Please help me in resolving this

Comment: If nothing of the below solution helps , try the steps given here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21995207/2789764

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 (and Vista) set access permissions on the Program Files directories and will not allow a normal user to write to those directories.

Either your program has to be run by an administrator, or you can change the permissions on your app's Program Files entry, or save the data somewhere else.

Comment: I have deployed a VSTO Excel Add-In so how can i run that in Administrator or how to change the permission on my Apps program file entrys

Comment: How are you deploying the add-in, are you using a Windows installer file?

Comment: Setup file created in dotnet .msi file

Answer (score 2):

It might be an idea to use the special folders .NET provides for this type of data. This should work:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\AppName\test folder");
```

Then write your data to this folder.

Comment: But i want to write it to installation path ie C:\Programfiles\myApp\myFolder

Comment: Is there a particular reason why it has to be this location?

Answer (score 0):

- Is your application running in the context of administrator?
- Is visual studio running as administrator?

To do this right click VS and select run as administrator, to do it permanently, right click, propertys and select the run as admin check box.

When your debugging your app through VS, it will need the permissions, else the application its self will.

Its probably just a permissions based thing...

Comment: I am using VS in Windows XP and deploying the exe in Win 7

Answer (score 0):

You can enable XP mode for an executable.

Comment: how can i do this for VSTO Excel Add-in

Comment: I was just adding that in windows 7 there is an option to run in XP mode not just as administrator. I would recomend not to create a folder in `C:\Programfiles\MyApplication\` but in `%APPDATA%\MyApplication\`

Comment: if i use APPDATA where would it create folder in Win 7 and Win XP??

Comment: @Sathish: Open a cmd and type `echo %APPDATA%`

Answer (score 0):

Please find the settings below

[link text](http://www.blogsdna.com/2159/how-to-take-ownership-grant-permissions-to-access-files-folder-in-windows-7.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Long time Windows XP developers should consider reading UAC,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control

It was first added in Windows Vista, and now becomes a central part of Windows family.

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULDN'T write to Program Files. It's a bad habit and only installers should write there. What you "want" is bad for the whole ecosystem and just plain wrong. Don't do it.